# Expressing English sentence using quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Statement:

Every real number can be written as a difference of two positive real numbers.

My attempt:

$$ (\forall x\in\Bbb R)(\exists a\in\Bbb R)(\exists b\in\Bbb R)(x=a-b)\;$$

How do I specify that the two numbers are positive using correct notation?

Also, I am not quite sure how to express the following:

“There is a smallest positive real number.”

Comment: $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$

Comment: Or, $\exists a\in \mathbb{R}, \exists b\in \mathbb{R}, a > 0 \wedge b > 0 \wedge x = a-b$.

Comment: Would I have to specify that x is a positive real number?

Comment: Could you please help me with the second one as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every real number can be written as the difference of two positive real numbers:

$$\forall r\in\mathbb{R}, \exists a\in\mathbb{R}^+, \exists b\in\mathbb{R}^+ : r=a-b.$$
There is a smallest positive number (which is not true):
$$ \exists s\in\mathbb{R}^+: \forall a\in\mathbb{R}^+, s\leq a$$
Not true since, according to the convention "*positive means positive*", i.e. $0\not\in\mathbb{R}^+$, that would imply $s\leq\frac{s}{2}$ and $1\leq \frac{1}{2}$ by the positivity of $s$.

Comment: i would not introduce the cross product....

Comment: @hyprfrco: then don't, but it is harmless. $$A\times B \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\{(a,b): a\in A, b\in B\}.$$

Comment: sure... i just, wouldnt suggest it at this precise moment...